# Tableau TABCMD utility "get url" to csv fills blanks with value from previous row

Tags: tableau-api

I am using tabcmd to get the data from the Tableau view following examples in the official documentation: https://help.tableau.com/current/server/en-us/tabcmd_cmd.htm#id7e0a0627-ad89-4135-a1c2-85b1d8472568

I have no problem extracting data itself, however, I have observed the discrepancy between what's in the file from tabcmd vs what I can see when I export the view from Tableau dashboard.

What is happening with the file that is produced by *tabcmd* is that any *blank results* (expected) in the data set gets *replaced* by the value from the previous row.

Is there any way to prevent this from happening?

Thanks